# How to set a bearer token param for testing a Rails API using Rswag UI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, swagger-ui, rswag

I'm having issues when testing my API using the Rswag UI gem. It seems that authorization headers are not being set properly in the UI after entering the token in the param field. Nevertheless, the test itself is passing and the endpoint is being hit when I run the test in the terminal. Please take a look at the image attached below for more info.

My authenticate method in the `application_controller` looks like this:

```
def authenticate!
    authenticate_or_request_with_http_token do |token, _|
      @auth = ApiKey.exists?(access_token: token)
    end
end
```

The `swagger_helper` security definition looks like this

```
  securityDefinitions: {
    Bearer: {
      description: '...',
      type: :apiKey,
      name: 'Authorization',
      in: :header
    }
  }
```

And the test, which is passing, looks like this:

```
require 'swagger_helper'

RSpec.describe 'Api::V1::Events', type: :request do

  let(:access_token) { FactoryBot.create(:api_key).access_token }
  let(:Authorization) { "Bearer #{access_token}" }

  path '/v1/events' do
    post 'Creates an event' do
      tags 'Events'
      consumes 'application/json'
      security [Bearer: {}]
      parameter name: :Authorization, in: :header, type: :string
      parameter name: :event, in: :body, schema: {
          type: :object,
          properties: {
              name: { type: :string },
              description: { type: :string },
              date: { type: :string },
              time: { type: :string }
          },
          required: [ 'name', 'description', 'date', 'time' ]
      }

      response '201', 'created' do
        let(:event) { { name: 'foo', description: 'bar', date: '2020-09-24', time: '00:00:00' } }
        run_test!
      end
    end
   end
 end
```

This is the line I'm struggling with: `parameter name: :Authorization, in: :header, type: :string` I've tried different types, such as, `http`, `string` and `apiKey` and I haven't had luck

The Curl that Swager UI should return should look like this:

```
curl -X POST "http://localhost:3000/v1/events" -H "accept: */*" -H 'Authorization: Bearer ab4d77e61a5ccdc402sb75867328ea77' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"name\":\"string\",\"description\":\"string\",\"date\":\"string\",\"time\":\"string\"}"
```

[image]

Comment: The Authorization header should be handled by the `security [Bearer: {}]` line. The parameter `parameter name: :Authorization, ...` is not needed. Instead, click the "Authorization" button at the top of Swagger UI, enter "Bearer <token>" there, and then test the request. Does this work?

Comment: It seems that the button you mentioned is not clickable, is there any configuration I should add to my helper to enable the button?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found a solution based on the comment I got. I was not seeing the `Authorize` button in the swagger UI. So I basically made some updates in the `swagger_helper` among other files

I changed this:

```
  'v1/swagger.yaml' => {
      openapi: '3.0.1',
   ...
```

To this

```
  'v1/swagger.json' => {
      swagger: '2.0',
      ....
   }
```

Also on the bottom of the file I changed `config.swagger_format = :yaml` to `config.swagger_format = :json`

Then I ran the following command: `rswag:specs:swaggerize` to generate the json file

I also made an update to the initializer from
`c.swagger_endpoint '/api-docs/v1/swagger.yaml', 'API V1 Docs'` to `c.swagger_endpoint '/api-docs/v1/swagger.json', 'API V1 Docs'`

Finally, I restarted the server and I was able to see the above mentioned button to enter the token.

Comment: with openapi: '3.0.1', this will work with yaml as well.

Answer (score 0):

The solution of going back to the previous version works, but I want to stay with `openapi: '3.0.1'` and I found the solution.

Without having to change everything to `json` I just have to add this section:

```rb
"v1/swagger.yaml" => {
 openapi: "3.0.1",
 ...,
 components: {
  securitySchemes: {
   Bearer: {
    type: :apiKey,
    name: 'Authorization',
    in: :header,
    description: 'Your Bearer token'
   }
  }
 }
}
```

We keep the property `security [Bearer: {}]` in the rspec file:

```rb
require 'swagger_helper'

RSpec.describe 'Api::V1::Events', type: :request do

  let(:access_token) { FactoryBot.create(:api_key).access_token }
  let(:Authorization) { "Bearer #{access_token}" }

  path '/v1/events' do
    post 'Creates an event' do
      tags 'Events'
      consumes 'application/json'
      # /////
      security [Bearer: {}]
      # /////
      parameter name: :Authorization, in: :header, type: :string
      parameter name: :event, in: :body, schema: {
          type: :object,
          properties: {
              name: { type: :string },
              description: { type: :string },
              date: { type: :string },
              time: { type: :string }
          },
          required: [ 'name', 'description', 'date', 'time' ]
      }

      response '201', 'created' do
        let(:event) { { name: 'foo', description: 'bar', date: '2020-09-24', time: '00:00:00' } }
        run_test!
      end
    end
   end
 end
```

This will display the "Authorize" button:
[image: Authorize button]

Then a modal will appear where you can load the token you want and that's it.
[image: Authorize modal]

Comment: I am trying the same thing, the above answer working perfectly fine, but when i tried your answer it is still giving me error. because authorization headers are not passing

Comment: @Vishal ensure that the `url` from which you query the API is the same as the `defaultHost`.

The same thing happens to me with authorization when, for example, I use the page with `http://127.0.0.1:8001/api-docs/index.html` instead of using it with `http://localhost:3001/api-docs /index.html`